# Writing to Files in python

Tags: python, file

I am creating a .txt file to store scores in my snake game. The problem is writing back into the file.
my current idea goes somewhat like this:

```
for line in open("scoreboard.txt", "r+"):
    line = scorelist[y] + namelist[y]
```

I've already read through the scores, made them into a list, and incorporated a new score, but I can't figure out how to simultaneously cycle through both a line and the lists i'm storing the data in to process, and overwrite the old scores.

Comment: You don't want to do that. Better to read the file first, make your changes, and then write a new file (the new file can be the same name as your old file). Or you can write to a temporary file, then rename that temporary file to `scoreboard.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) encoding to store simple objects into a file:

```
import json

myscore = [1,2,5]
mynames = ["foo","bar","baz"]

#save
with open("scores.json","w") as f:
    json.dump({'score' : myscore, 'names': mynames},f)

#load
with open("scores.json","r") as f:
    content = json.load(f)
    loadedScore = content['score']
    loadedNames = content['names']
```